# Angular Module not available when using $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm getting a curious error similar to some other posts, but I haven't been able to remedy. I'm using jQuery's document.ready() to ensure that all the buttons are loaded before referencing my local Javascript file that includes an AngularJS front-end incorporated with Firebase and Angularfire.

I'm getting the following error in the console that typically accompanies an Angular controller with an unreferenced or uninitialized dependency injection:

> Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either
>   misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
>       If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I wrote this code while following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HhM8CugHoE) on Youtube and basically copied everything the same except including the aforementioned jQuery.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Piano Lessons Administrator Signup</title>

    <!--Jquery-->
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!--AngularJS-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>

    <!--Firebase Dependency-->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.0/firebase.js"></script>

    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

    <!--Local Javascript-->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(function(){
          $.getScript('javascripts/piano.js');  
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>


   <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-congroller="MyCtrl as ctrl">

        <pre>{{ ctrl.object | json }} </pre>

      </div> <!--End myCtrl-->
   </body>

...
</html>
```

...and Piano.js

```
(function () {

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "myApikey",
    authDomain: "myAuthDomain",
    databaseURL: "myDatabaseURL",
    projectId: "projectId",
    storageBucket: "myStorageBucket",
    messagingSenderId: "MyMessagingSender"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var myApp = angular
    .module('myApp', ['firebase'])
    .config(function ($firebaseRefProvider) {
    $firebaseRefProvider.registerUrl({
        default: config.databaseURL,
        object: `${config.databaseURL}/angular/object`
    });  
})
    .factory('ObjectFactory', ObjectFactory)
    .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function ObjectFactory($firebaseObject, $firebaseRef){
    return $firebaseObject($firebaseRef.object);
}

function MyCtrl(ObjectFactory){
    this.object = ObjectFactory;
    this.sayHello = () => {
    //console.log(this.object.name);
        return `Hello, ${this.object.name}`;
    }
}

const ctrl = new MyCtrl({ name: 'David' });
const message = ctrl.sayHello();
console.log(message);

...
}());
```

Interestingly, The console.log(message) does seem to work, which seems like it would need the module to be working for the controller and factory to be working, but the object in the  tag does not compile leaving it plain text, which usually means the controller has failed. Does putting it inside the $(document).ready() take the other  tags out of scope?

Comment: No idea why you would need to load this using `getScript` but if you do you need to manually bootstrap the app rather than using `ng-app`

Comment: @charlietfl there are parts that I left out (specifically some input boxes and their related javascript) that would throw errors for elements not found if placed in the header, but the Angular wouldn't load if the script was included in the body.

Comment: Probably those scripts should be in directives. But even with manual bootstrap approach you should be able to include your script in script tag

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, I'll give it a try, but I will have to admit that I am still very new to much of this and I don't know exactly what "Manual Bootsrap" entails. Do you have any suggested resources before I just start searching?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap

Comment: @charlietfl Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the module is loaded after the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event, the app needs to be manually bootstrapped.

First remove the auto-bootstrap directive:

```
 <body ̶n̶g̶-̶a̶p̶p̶=̶"̶m̶y̶A̶p̶p̶"̶ >
```

Then manually bootstrap the app after the module has been loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
      $.getScript('javascripts/piano.js');
      angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['myApp']);  
  });
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)
- [AngularJS `angular.bootstrap` API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)
- [jQuery `ready()` API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)